# How to make a pivot table out of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame( {'level01': [10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 'level02': [110, 210, 150, 310, 410, 510, 610], 'value01': [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3], 'value02': [0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]} )

>>> df
   level01  level02  value01  value02
0       10      110        1        0
1       20      210        0        3
2       20      150        0        0
3       30      310        2        1
4       40      410        0        0
5       50      510        0        0
6       60      610        3        1
```

Each value colume corresponds to its level column. For example, `df['value01'][0]`, which is 1, means the value of level `df['level01'][0]`, which is 10. (the value of level 10 is 1)

I want to extract every value row that is **0** with its level and make a pivot table. So, the result would be like:

```
   level, value
0     20      2
1     40      1
2     50      1
3    110      1
4    150      1
5    410      1
6    510      1
```

I tried `df.pivot_table( values=df[['value01', 'value02']], index=df[['level01', 'level02']], aggfunc='count')`, but the result is quite different from what I thought.

```
                value01  value02
level01 level02                  
10      110            1        1
20      150            1        1
        210            1        1
30      310            1        1
40      410            1        1
50      510            1        1
60      610            1        1
```

How can I get the result I want? I'd appreciate it  if I could get some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` in columns, reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), so possible filter only `0` values by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and last get count per groups by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(list(zip(*s.str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)').values.tolist())))
df2 = (df.stack()
         .query('value == 0')
         .groupby('level')
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='value'))

print (df2)
   level  value
0     20      2
1     40      1
2     50      1
3    110      1
4    150      1
5    410      1
6    510      1
```

Solution if only `2` columns is create helper `DataFrame` with [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) in first step:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'level': df[['level01', 'level02']].values.ravel(),
                   'value': df[['value01', 'value02']].values.ravel()})

df2 = (df1.query('value == 0')
          .groupby('level')
          .size()
          .reset_index(name='value'))
```

Comment: Thank you again for the detailed answer! I've learned a lot thanks to you!